# Log errors for 2sxc in DNN

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

Recently I have installed last version of DNN (9.10.2) and last LTS version of 2sxc (12.8.1)

Everything is working as expected but after check DNN logs I found this error

```
DotNetNuke.Web.Mvc.Extensions.StartupExtensions - Unable to configure services for ToSic.Sxc, Version=12.8.1.26412, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, see exception for details 
- LoaderException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features, Version=1.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes()
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()
   at DotNetNuke.DependencyInjection.Extensions.TypeExtensions.SafeGetTypes(Assembly assembly, ILog logger)
```

As I said 2sxc is working without any problem but is generating in back those logs.

Maybe is needed to add or install some framework or component in server ?

ANY idea

Comment: Not sure about this, sorry. 2sxc 13 to be released this week will use a different set of DLLs anyhow, so maybe you can just ignore for a few more days ;)

Comment: Ok, Thanks for clearing the issue. No problem, as I said module is working without any problem is just appearing in logs.